# How to get sum using java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **33** | **6** | **0** |
| 79 | 6 | 8 |
| 13 | 4 | 0 |
| **12** | **6** | **0** |
| **K100** | **6** | **0** |

Let's say I want to sum up the A values iff B = 6 and C = 0. So I would sum up 33 + 12 + 100 to get 145.

`A` can contain letters like `K100` which should be ignored and handled like if it was `100`. How can I achieve this using streams?

```
answer += someObj.someList() # answer should be 145
.stream()
.filter(e -> e != null && e.getB() == 6 && e.getC == 0
... // what goes here?
```

Comment: `.map` (or `.mapToInt`) and `.sum`?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am confused.  Your question implies B and C are integers. But your commented solution is checking equality to strings.  I am assuming only column A is a string.  It is easily altered if not the case.

I would consider a slight improvement to the other answer.  `Integer.parseInt` already returns an int so you can change the prior `map` to `mapToInt`  In your example the final map simply reboxes the `int` value to extract an `int` value.  I am using a record as a demo class.

```
record Data(String getA, int getB, int getC) {
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    

List<Data> someList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Data("33", 6, 0), new Data("79", 6, 8),
        new Data("13", 4, 0), new Data("12", 6, 0),
        new Data("K100", 6, 0)));

long answer = someList.stream()
        .filter(e -> e != null && e.getB() == 6
                && e.getC() == 0)
        .mapToInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(
                e.getA().replaceAll("\\D", "")))
        .sum();

System.out.println(answer);
```

prints

```
145
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question was missing some Code I add here the Code which I assume for my first answer

```
public class Data {
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    private Integer c;
    
    public Data(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

You have to do a mapToInt() with e.getA() returning an Integer followed by sum()

```
    List<Data> someList = Arrays.asList(
            new Data(33, 6, 0), new Data(79, 6, 8),
            new Data(13, 4, 0), new Data(12, 6, 0),
            new Data(100, 6, 0));

    Integer sumOfA = someList.stream()
            .filter(e -> e != null && e.getB() == 6 && e.getC() == 0)
            .mapToInt(Data::getA).sum();
```

As stated in the question, a should be a String. Therefore my answer would  look like the accepted one.

```
public class Data {
    private String a;
    private Integer b;
    private Integer c;
    
    public Data(String a, Integer b, Integer c) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

and

```
    List<Data> someList = Arrays.asList(
            new Data("33", 6, 0), new Data("79", 6, 8),
            new Data("13", 4, 0), new Data("12", 6, 0),
            new Data("K100", 6, 0));

    Predicate<Data> dataNotNull = Objects::nonNull ;
    Predicate<Data> bEqualsSix = e -> e.getB() == 6 ;
    Predicate<Data> cEqualsZero = e -> e.getC() == 0 ;
    ToIntFunction<Data> mapToInt = e-> Integer.parseInt(
            e.getA().replaceAll("\\D", ""));
    
    Integer sumOfA = someList.stream()
            .filter(dataNotNull.and(bEqualsSix).and(cEqualsZero))
            .mapToInt(mapToInt).sum();
```

Comment: @WJS in the first Version A was only Integer (100 instead of K100) Therefore I added condition `e.getA() returning an Integer`. And yes: it has to be `Data::getA` and I copied error `e.getC` instead corret `e.getC()`  from question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Elements in A are Strings you could use regular expressions to remove Letters from the value. The Expression for a non-digit Charakter ist `\D`. The regex can be applied by using `.map()`. The complete answer would then look like.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\d+");
int result = someObj.someList()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e != 
                        null && e.getB() == 6 && e.getC == 0)
                    .map(s -> 
                        Integer.parseInt(s.getA().repalceAll("[\\D]","")))
                    
                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                    .sum()
```

Comment: `long answer = someList.stream().filter(e ->e != null && Objects.equals(e.getB(), "6") && Objects.equals(e.getC(), "0")).map(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getA().replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();` This is what I came up with. Would your way be better and if so why?

Comment: @T27392 Your implementation feels definitly more elegant.  I dont see any Advantage of my particular solution. I will Update my answer